# Nightmare Looping

Tags: node.js, nightmare

Hello, I am writing an application where I need to be able to loop through an array of urls. I know there is an example of how to do this but my issue is a little different, I will explain with some code.

```
nightmare
  .goto('some url')
  .evaluate(() => {
    //evaluate code
  })
  .then(dataArray => {
    var innerRun = function* () {
      var returnData = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        var item = dataArray[i];
        yield nightmare
          .goto(item.url)
          .evaluate(function () {
            return false;
          })
          .screenshot(item.imgPath)
        returnData.push(item);
      }
      return returnData;
    }
    vo(innerRun)(function (err, ads) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error running", err)
        return;
      }
    });
  });
```

I would like to be able to loop that code by using an array of urls. I had issues implementing this I believe because I am already doing it inside the `then`. It would stop running once it hit the `yield nightmare` inside the `then`

```
var mainLoop = function* () {
  for (var j = 0; j < urlArray.length; j++) {
    var url = urlArray[j];
    yield nightmare.goto(url)//same code as in example above
  }
}

vo(mainLoop)(function (err, d) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error running", err)
    return;
  }
});
```

The above code is what I attempted to do. If anyone has any ideas it would be a huge help thank you!

Comment: What are you requirements for running all these requests?  Do you want to run them serially, one after another.  As many in parallel as practical?  All in parallel?  And, what is the desired end result?  An array of snapshots?  What do you want to do if you get an error along the way - stop and report the error, skip the error and keep going on the others?

Comment: If possible I would like to run as many in parallel as possible. I thought you needed to do one after another because of the nightmare instance but if they could be run in parallel that would be great. The end result is saving the snapshots and logging innerData array returned by `vo(innerRun)`. If there is an error I would like to log this error but keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
var urls = ['http://example.com', 'http://example2.com', 'http://example3.com'];

var results = [];
urls.forEach(function(url) {
  nightmare.goto(url)
    .wait('body')
    .title()
    .then(function(result) {
      results.push(result);
    });
});
console.dir(results)
```

Source: https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md